# how do we renew idtoken using msal?

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-msal, msal.js

I am currently trying to develop an SPA application with a webapi, I am using msal for login. The flow is the user logs in, gets an idtoken (used to authorize for my api), gets an access token (for graph api) using acquiretokensilent method. I renew the idToken right before an hour using acquiretokensilent by passing clientID in scopes. But still the I am logged out after the idToken expires. I see that it doesn't get refreshed in the browser storage.

SO my question is, is there anyway I can renew the id Token and keep the user logged in? Any help will be great.

Answer (score 2):

> acquireTokenSilent(scopes: Array, authority?: string, user?: User, extraQueryParameters?: string): Promise - Used to get the token from cache. MSAL will return **the cached token if it is not expired** Or it will send a request to the STS to obtain an access token using a hidden iframe. To renew an idToken, the clientId should be passed as the only scope in the scopes array.

https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/wiki/Public-APIs

Any chance that when you try to refresh your token, you're actually retrieving it from the cache because it isn't expired yet?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I did read through this documentation, I did check the token expiry time and it does renew so I am sure it is not getting from cache.

Answer (score 2):

The expiration time for ID tokens in Azure AD is 1 hour. As long as the user session with AAD is active, the acquireTokenSilent method will be able to renew the idtokens. However, if the AAD session is expired, the token renewal will result in a failure. You will need to handle the failure with an interactive call prompting user to sign in again.

You can read [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-configurable-token-lifetimes#single-sign-on-session-tokens) for ways to extend the Signed in AAD session. Also, you have the option to configure the lifetime policy for id tokens as documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-configurable-token-lifetimes#token-lifetime-policy-properties).

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately AAD does not support refreshing the ID token. Only the access token can be refreshed. See here: [https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/active-directory-protocols-oauth-code/#refreshing-the-access-tokens](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow#refreshing-the-access-tokens.). Besides, if you want to know more about token,please refer to the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v1-id-and-access-tokens).

Comment: I am not refreshing it, I am trying to renew it. When you pass only appid as scope to acquiretokensilent method you get a new idToken. I know implicit flow doesn't allow you to refresh tokens.

Answer (score 0):

you can use sso through which you can get a new id_token here you can.

if the time difference between token and current exceed 5 minutes then it will get new token from sso
Beware that this will work when you have an active session.

```
 this.adalSvc.instance.acquireTokenSilent(tokenRequest)
                .then( (token: any) => {
                   const rem_id_token_Time = this.diff_minutes(new Date(token.idTokenClaims.exp * 1000), new Date());
                   console.log(rem_id_token_Time);
                   if ( rem_id_token_Time > 5) {
                     this.shared.refreshToken(token.idToken, token.accessToken);
                     resolve (token.accessToken);
                   } else {
 
                       const ssoRequest = { loginHint: token.account.username };
                       this.adalSvc.instance.ssoSilent(ssoRequest)
                         .then(() => {
                           this.shared.refreshToken(token.idToken, token.accessToken);
                           resolve (token.accessToken);
                         })
                         .catch(error => {
                           reject(error);
                         });
                   }
 
                   }
```

diff_minutes(dt2, dt1) {

```
  var diff =(dt2.getTime() - dt1.getTime()) / 1000;
  diff /= 60;
  return Math.abs(Math.round(diff));

}
```